# Python - Convert a 2 (or less) item set to 2 variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

My code works but I feel like the while loop is possibly not as succinct as it could be.

Maybe using a while loop for a set of 2 items or less is silly? I'm not sure.

```
# <SETUP CODE TO SIMULATE MY SITUATION>

import random
import re

# The real data set is much larger than this (Around 1,000 - 10,000 items):
names = {"abc", "def", "123"}

if random.randint(0, 3):
    # foo value is "foo" followed by a string of unknown digits:
    names.add("foo" + str(random.randint(0, 1000)))
if random.randint(0, 3):
    # bar value is just "bar":
    names.add("bar")
print("names:", names)

matches = {name for name in names if re.match("foo|bar", name)}
print("matches:", matches)

# In the names variable, foo and/or bar may be missing, thus len(matches) should be 0-2:
assert len(matches) <= 2, "Somehow got more than 2 matches"

# </SETUP CODE TO SIMULATE MY SITUATION>

foo, bar = None, None
while matches:
    match = matches.pop()
    if match == "bar":
        bar = match
    else:
        foo = match

print("foo:", foo)
print("bar:", bar)
```

And here's what else I've tried within the while loop:

1. I know ternaries don't work like this (at least not in Python) but this is the pipe-dream level of simplicity I was hoping for:

   ```
   (bar if match == "bar" else foo) = match
   ```
2. The remove function doesn't return anything:

   ```
   try:
       bar = matches.remove("bar")
   except KeyError:
       foo = matches.pop()
   ```

Comment: i did not get your point. You added two `if random.randint(0, 3):` right next to each other. why is it so? you can copy the second `if` code and append it first `if` and remove the second `if`.

Comment: @UmarAsghar If I combined the `if` statements into one then there would only be two possible scenarios: "foo" and "bar" are both added to the set, or neither "foo" nor "bar" are added to the set. However I want four possible scenarios to show what my data set is like: 1. "foo" and "bar" both added to set. 2. Just "foo" added to set. 3. Just "bar" added to set. 4. Neither "foo" nor "bar" added to set.

Comment: Ok, so it because of your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop in your first code is ok, 10,000 inputs is really small at computer scale.

If you want to go slightly faster you can just browse your list `match` without popping elements (which takes more time), replacing simply

```
while matches:
    match = matches.pop()
```

by

```
for match in matches:
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why I overlooked this. I guess I thought `pop()` was helping with the garbage collection by emptying out the set. But since it's a 2 item set that seems negligible anyway.

Comment: No it does not help. When you get to the end of your script, `matches` memory space is instantly freed. If you pop 10,000 times, you will have 10,000 memory freeing attempts. Even if the quantity of memory to free is 10,000 smaller than the whole set, it doesn't mean it takes 10,000 less time (freeing a small or large amount of memory is equivalent in time).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use simple for loop instead of while loop

```
for match in matches:
    bar = match if match == 'bar' else foo = match

print("foo:", foo)
print("bar:", bar)
```

You don't have to remove the element from the set every time. Since your set only contains 2 or fewer elements :P. Maybe for larger sets you can delete the entire set after use by

```
del matches # will help in garbage collection.
```

In our case, this is not needed.